# More sophisticated case of "me and I"!

Tags: subjects, objects

Which of the following is correct?
"I agree that it will be just me and you managing the projects."
or
"I agree that it will be just I and you managing the projects."

Comment: What is the question? Be specific, provide the research you have done before asking the question and explain your doubts as to why you think one variant or the other would be incorrect.

Comment: To be clear, you are comparing "just me and you" with "just I and you"?

Answer (score 1):

"Me". You can judge this by considering the following different ways to say what you mean: "it will be just us" and "it will be just we". Now if "we" sounds wrong to you, then "I and you" should also sound wrong and for the same reason: the pronouns "we" and "I" are in subject case. So if you prefer "us", then also prefer "me and you".

Comment: "I agree that it will be just you and myself managing the projects" sounds better than either to my ears. There would be a register clash otherwise. "I agree that it'll be just you and me managing the projects" works less formally.

Comment: The question compared "just me and you" with "just I and you." You have addressed you and I.